# Flutter: Create map from list using a delimiter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store a list of activities with a specific color locally and trying to convert the list into either a map or a list of lists.

Using shared preferences to save the data locally I have the following list:

```
List<String> value = ['Sleep: Blue', 'Meditation: Green', 'Running: Red'];
prefs.setStringList('ActivityList', value);  //save data locally
```

But I want to be able to retrieve an object of the form:

```
values = [ {'Sleep', 'Blue'}, {'Meditation', 'Green'}, {'Running', 'Red'} ];
```

What would be the best way to do this and how would I use the delimiter ':' to split the data accordingly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by array of objects. If you simply want an array of pairs, then the following should work for you

```dart
value.map((item) => item.split(": "))
```

Or if you want a key value map from your data, then you can do something like this:

```dart
Map.fromEntries(value.map((item) {
   List<String> pair = item.split(": ");
   return MapEntry(pair[0], pair[1]);
}));
```